# Dreamhost Shared Hosting - Increase post_max_size

Tags: php, shared-hosting, dreamhost, file-size

I am using Dreamhost shared hosting running PHP 5.4 and I am trying to increase the file upload limit to 1 GB. I try to achieve that by using `.user.ini` and putting the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
```

When I check the `phpinfo()`, it does shows that local value has been changed to 1GB. But when I try upload large file, I only manage to get file size below 100MB successfully uploaded.

Why can't I get file size over 100MB to be uploaded? Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: why do you need 1024M upload size? Use FTP whenever possible.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar The new YouTube... maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamhost does not support significant increases in `upload_max_filesize`.   From their [documentation](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP.ini):

> **Note**: Some variables (in particular, `memory_limit`, `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`) are subject to internal limitations; increasing them significantly beyond the default values will not work correctly and will cause issues with your site.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your answer. Do you use Dreamhost? Do you know what is the maximum value that will work in Dreamhost?

Comment: I do use dreamhost, but I have never tried to change the value myself.  [Their forums](https://www.google.com/search?q=dreamhost+upload_max_filesize+site:discussion.dreamhost.com) have lots of threads from people who have tried to change the value.   It appears that it is somewhat dependent on which machine you are running on at dreamhost and which cgi module you are using.

Comment: Off-topic: I went to find a website that would convert Fahrenheit to Kelvins and found http://ostermiller.org/calc/temperature.html. I did not realize who's site I was on until the end when I saw the favicon and recognized it. Thanks!! Nice tool! Helps me plan my oil consumption for my apartment building which is scary expensive. I should take up drinking- it is cheaper! Thanks again! You can delete this if you want.